# Display multiple data array in one column depending on value in material table of Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, mat-table

I have this data. How to display in table when service value is true?
Something like this below.

Table should be:

```
ID     Services
5      service1,service3
```

Data:

```
  {   
    id: 5, 
    services:
    { 
       service1: true, 
       service2: false, 
       service3: true, 
    }
  }
```

html

```
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>QTY</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchaseOrder">{{purchaseOrder.id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

     <ng-container matColumnDef="services"> 
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Equipment Ordered</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchaseOrder">{{purchaseOrder.services}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom method in your component that filters the services:

```
getRequiredServices(servicesObject) {
 return Object.keys(servicesObject).filter(service => servicesObject[service]).join();
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="services">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Equipment Ordered</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let purchaseOrder">{{getRequiredServices(purchaseOrder.services)}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**update**

Modify the method this way fr what you asked in the comments(return a string which has all the truthy properties):

```
getRequiredServices(servicesObject) {
  return Object.entries(servicesObject).reduce(
    (requiredServices, [key, value]) => {
      if (typeof value === 'boolean' && value) {
        requiredServices.push(key);
      } else if (typeof value === 'string' && value) {
        requiredServices.push(value);
      }
      return requiredServices;
    },
    []
  ).join();
}
```

Comment: Hello, nothing is showing on the table. also is it checking if the value is true or false? thanks

Comment: @user10860402 - Yes, it should return the services that are true.

Comment: It worked now thank you. do you mind if i asked a follow up question? what if i have another property inside services that is "services4: 'string here' ". how can i also show the value of string if it is not null? thank you

Comment: @user10860402 - If the new property has a string as its value then the function will work without any changes because a string is a true value.

Comment: i mean show the value of the string if it is not null or empty?

Comment: @user10860402 -  If the new property is `services4: 'something'` your `mat-cell` will have it. If the new property is `services4: ''` or `services4: null` it will not show up.

Comment: i want it to show 'something' instead of 'service4' if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214790/discussion-between-ramesh-and-user10860402).